# Error occurs during compilation in cygwin version 1.7.30(0.272/5/3)

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin

I am facing some issues when compiling code in Cygwin version 1.7.30(0.272/5/3) but when I use Cygwin version 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) to compile the same code it gets compiled successfully.
The following issue occurs during compilation:

1. `gcc-3: Command not found` When I use gcc-3 in my makefile. But if i use gcc it works finely. I found `/cygwin/bin/gcc-3` exe is missing in the updated package.
2. `gcc: error:unrecognized command line option 'wall'`
3. `gcc: error:unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'`
4. `gcc: error:unrecognized command line option '-Wl'`
5. `gcc: error:unrecognized command line option '--add-stdcalll-alias'`

Did I miss any package during installation of cygwin? What do I need to do to resolve all these issues?

Comment: `wall` should be `-Wall`

Comment: Thanks, 2nd error is solved. What I need to do to solve the rest of the errors?